# How to overwrite a file everyday in blob storage and load into external table

Tags: ssis, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I am trying to create a SSIS package with blob storage. I want to overwirte the file in blob with latest file and want to load the file to external table.
Could you please any body help me how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

The file overwrite can be controlled by the data movement activity that places the data to the import folder/location. As for automating SSIS in Azure, you are going to need Azure Data Factory, as it allows for SSIS functionality in the runtime environment in Azure. And then PowerShell can be used to automate the process: [Provision the Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime in Azure Data Factory with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure-powershell)

[Load data into Azure SQL Data Warehouse with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-sql-data-warehouse?view=sql-server-2017)
[Move data to or from Azure Blob Storage using SSIS connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/move-data-to-azure-blob-using-ssis)

Answer (score 0):

I do this with SSIS. You don't need to use Data Factory. Of course like anything, there are many ways to do the same thing. At a high level, here is what I do in my SSIS package:

- **Data Flow Task** - I create a flat file from a OLEDB data source.
- **Azure Blob Upload Task** - I upload the file to Azure Blob Storage
- **Execute SQL Task** - I execute a stored procedure that bulk inserts the data from the blob to a table in Azure SQL.
- **File System Task** - I delete the local copy of the file.

Here are some prerequisites:
 1. Execute the following statement for the account you use to connect to SQL Azure:
`GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS to <login>`

2. Create a scoped database credential:

   CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL myScopedCredential
   WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
   SECRET = ''; --Paste SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE from Azure portal here
3. Create an external data source like this:

   CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE myExternalDataSource
   WITH  (
       TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
       LOCATION = 'https://myAzureAccount.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer', 
       CREDENTIAL = myScopedCredential
   );
4. Create a format file that describes the file that you are bulk importing into SQL Server. This is the most convoluted part of the process. Read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Your insert statement (or stored proc) will look something like this:

```
    BULK INSERT dbo.myTable FROM 'myContainer/myFile.txt' 
    WITH(DATA_SOURCE = 'myExternalDataSource',
    FORMATFILE = 'format/format_myFile.xml',
    FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'myExternalDataSource')
```

There are lots of different arguments you can use with [bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that I have not included in the code sample above, so be sure to test out what works best in your situation.